# SOAP interceptor for .NET?

Tags: .net, xml, soap, debugging

I'm working with an API and my results (CRUD) are getting mangled somehow in the return and .NET is throwing invalid XML errors.  Is there a setup trick to getting tcpmon to work with a debugger in Visual Studio?  Or is there another lightweight interceptor/analyzer that I can use to capture the XML?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use System.Net.[Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty48b824.aspx) to view the data. Just add this to the configuration on client or server.

You need to set `maxdatasize` to a high value.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use [Microsoft's SOAP Toolkit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=C943C0DD-CEEC-4088-9753-86F052EC8450&displaylang=en). This little package includes a trace utility that can sit in between your client and web service to help with debugging the SOAP messages.

It's not free, but [Altova's XML Spy](http://www.altova.com/xmlspy) also has a SOAP debugger.

Hope these help!

Answer (score 1):

I use [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) to test my web services and it will give more detailed statistics on requests and responses than I've ever imagined.

Comment: this tool is awesome, thanks for the heads up on that.  It's great for navigating a new service and kicking the tires.  cheers!